# Can I get combinations of plugin by using selenium web-driver?

Tags: automation, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use combinations of plugins in a browser instance. Lets say, I have a profile named "Profile1". I have 3 plugins installed in this profile. Now I want web-driver to create a browser instance that will load only 1st and 2nd plugin, then another instance will load 2nd and 3rd plugin. I am not sure if it is possible with web-driver or not. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the firefox profile manager to create diffrent profiles please refere [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)

You can use diffrent firefox profile with webdriver.for example if you have a firefox profile with name 'ProfileName'. You can use the same with webdriver as below.

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("ProfileName");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: In that case I have make different profile with different combinations of plugins. My question was not that. I want the web-driver to use different combinations of plugins. Suppose you have installed flash and firebug in "ProfileName", i want to use only flash, not firebug. And also I don't want to create another profile with only flash installed.

Comment: This is the best way I can think of. Not sure if we can use diffrent plugins with webdriver by creating profile at runtime.